# DependencyProperty with ObservableCollection bound to a Datagrid

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I am trying to learn a new thing in WPF, and I just can't get it to work. I have declared a DependencyProperty, and I am trying to use it to bind a observable collection to a datagrid.
This is my code:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty dpActivityProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("dpActivity",
            typeof(ObservableCollection<Activity>),
            typeof(MainWindow));

        public ObservableCollection<Activity> dpActivity
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<Activity>)GetValue(dpActivityProperty); }
            set { SetValue(dpActivityProperty, value); }
        }
```

Here is my xaml:

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGrid Name="DG1" ItemsSource="{Binding dpActivity,ElementName=Utils}"
```

Utils is the x:Name of the mainwindow.

The problem I am having is that no data is displayed in my datagrid. There are no binding errors, and I can see the data if I don't use the dependency property and just set the itemssource to the observable collection. I have tried to google this, and no luck. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I put another datagrid on the project, and set autogeneratecolumns=true. This displays the data from dpActivity. the error must be in this code:

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
                                <WpfToolkit:DataGridTextColumn
                                    Header="Sport"
                                    Width="90"
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=Sport}" />
```

There are still no binding errors.

Wow! I am sorry I wasted everyone's time, I found a DG1.ItemsSource = Null statement that I forgot to comment out. That overrode everything to give me a empty datagrid. Everything works great now. Sorry again

Comment: This looks fine, do you really have no binding errors whatsoever?

Comment: Where have you set your DP? Can you post that code?

Comment: I have checked, and no binding errors, here is how I set dpActivity: dpActivity = myActivityReturn(out myActrec); where myActivityReturn returns a observable collection of type <Activity>. If I examine dpActivity It is full of data. This is very confusing

Comment: Upon review, I think the problem lies here<WpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
                                <WpfToolkit:DataGridTextColumn
                                    Header="Sport"
                                    Width="90"
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=Sport}" /> if I put a datagrid in the project, and set autogeneratecolumns = true, it works, and I can see the data. So the binding on the columns must be wrong.